# Is there a way to fix this FxCop CA2103 warning on a custom System.Security.IPermission implementaion?

Tags: c#, .net, fxcop

I have a class that implements `IPermission`:

```
public class MySecurityPermission : IPermission
{
    private string[] _demandRoles;
    private string[] _denyRoles;

    public MySecurityPermission(string[] demandRoles, string[] denyRoles)
    {
        this._demandRoles = demandRoles;
        this._denyRoles = denyRoles;
    }
}
```

Now, the IPermission interface requires a `Copy()` method, which I implemented as:

```
public IPermission Copy()
{
    return new MySecurityPermission(this._demandRoles.ToArray(), this._denyRoles.ToArray());
}
```

Note that the `.ToArray()` calls are there because it makes a close/copy of the array, and returns a new array instance, instead of passing the same array around.

This results in an FxCop CA2103:

> "Review the following for a possible security vulnerability: 
>                      In 'MySecurityPermission.Copy()', the return value 
>                      of a call to 'Enumerable.ToArray(this 
>                      IEnumerable)' is being passed to a 'MySecurityPermission' 
>                      constructor."

Is there a way to "fix" this? I'm not really sure why FxCop is even complaining about it. If someone could explain it, that would be great.

Comment: What happens if you mark your fields as `readonly`?

Comment: A little more info for your reading pleasure (not sure if it will help): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182309(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @vcsjones - that was my initial reaction too, but that interface also requires a `FromXML()` method, where I need to set the values in those arrays based on XML, hence they can't be readonly :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would appear that the rule is being raised because of where the code gets executed. If you create the variables first the rule will pass:

```
public IPermission Copy()
{
    var demand = _demandRoles.ToArray();
    var deny = _denyRoles.ToArray();
    return new MySecurityPermission(demand, deny);
}
```

Comment: Ah, good call.  I started trying to fix it myself by manually doing an `Array.Copy()` into a new variable, and passing that to the constructor instead. That too seems to work, but your solution is easier. I'm surprised FxCop sees a difference. I would have expected the IL code to be roughly the same.  Thanks!